# Java Enum sorting descending to the value

Tags: java, sorting, enums

I am having a bit of a problem trying to get the sorting done correctly.  I have a java program that references an enum and am trying to get the enum to be sorted ascending and descending.

My enum is as follows:

```
public enum EnumList
{
   A("A", "D", 5),
   B("C", "E", 2),
   C("B", "G", 3);

   private final String bT;
   private final String bA;
   private final int bP;

   EnumList( String t, String a, int p )
   {
     bT = t;
     bA = a;
     bP = p;
   }

   public String getT()
   {
     return bT;
   }
   public String getA()
   {
     return bA;
   }
   public int getP()
   {
     return bP;
   }
}
```

My main is as follows:

```
public class EnumMain
{
   public static class main( String[] args )
   {
     List<EnumList> elist = new ArrayList<EnumList>();

     String response = null;
     Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

     System.out.println( "Please select how you would like the list sorted" );
     System.out.println( "A for ascending, D for descending." );
     System.out.println( "Please select sort order: " );
     response = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

     if( response.equals( "A" ) )
     {
        elist.SortOrder(ASCENDING).valuesOf( getT() );
     }
     else if( response.equals( "D" ) )
     {
       elist.SortOrder(DESCENDING).valuesOf( getT() );
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println( "You have chosen a wrong response, please try again." );
        response = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
     }
  }
}
```

The issue with this is that not matter what I do the output is always:

```
A D 5
C E 2
B G 3
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong to get this to work.  I have been searching everything but the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SortOrder.html leaves a lot to be desired.  From what I have read there it looks correct, but it is not working.

Comment: What is the field that you want sort regarding it?

Comment: The first field should be the one sorted on.... the one that is A C B in the output.  I know the second field is sorted Ascending, but that was put in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Collections.sort` on your list, it's just a one liner:

```
...
if (response.equals("A")) {
    Collections.sort(elist, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getP(), o2.getP()));
}
else if (response.equals("D")) {
    Collections.sort(elist, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o2.getP(), o1.getP()));
}
...
```

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a `List<EnumList>` I would resort to using the `java.util.Collections` class (it does not matter that they are Enum fields - treat them like any normal Java object):

```
if(response.equals("A")) {
  // sort in ascending order
  Collections.sort(elist, new Comparator<>() {
    public int compare(EnumList itemOne, EnumList itemTwo) {
      return itemOne.getT().compareTo(itemTwo.getT());
    }
  });
} else if(response.equals("D")) {
  // sort in descending order
  Collections.sort(elist, new Comparator<>() {
    public int compare(EnumList itemOne, EnumList itemTwo) {
      return itemTwo.getT().compareTo(itemOne.getT());
    }
  });
}
```

PS: In Java 8 you could use the equivalent Lambda Expression:

```
if(response.equals("A")) {
  // sort in ascending order
  Collections.sort(elist, (itemOne, itemTwo) -> itemOne.getT().compareTo(itemTwo.getT()));
} else if(response.equals("D")) {
  // sort in descending order
  Collections.sort(elist, (itemOne, itemTwo) -> itemTwo.getT().compareTo(itemOne.getT()));
}
```

Comment: It is a shame I am not using Java 8, I am used to using lambda expressions with C#.  Would you switch what I itemOne and itemTwo are to go in the opposite direction?

Comment: Correct, `itemTwo.getT().compareTo(itemOne.getT())` would give you the descending order. Or multiplying the result with `-1`.

Comment: @MikeMastro btw. how come you accept the answer that is not sorting by the first column in your question, but the last (the Integer)?

Comment: Actually I used the A and D in the response.equals for Ascending and Descending.

Comment: I get that. But I was referring to your comment on your question "The first field should be the one sorted on..."